# C++17 error: "expected primary-expression before '.' token" when passing enum value to function

Tags: c++

Writing a small project. Need to pass value from enum into function.
Compilling using G++. `gcc version 9.3.0 (Homebrew GCC 9.3.0_1)`  with `-std=c++17`

```
enum memberType {DIRECTORY, EXECUTABLE, BASIC}; // Types member can be (basic - default file)
struct directoryMember{ // Directory member basic structure
    std::string name;
    std::string ext;
    memberType type;
};
directoryMember defineDirectoryMember(std::string n, std::string e, memberType t){ // Returns structure from raw parameters
    struct directoryMember tmp;
    tmp.name = n;
    tmp.ext = e;
    tmp.type = t;
}

const directoryMember previousDirectory = defineDirectoryMember("..", "", memberType.DIRECTORY);
```

When compilling I get error `error: expected primary-expression before '.' token` in line where I'm calling defineDirectoryMember()

Thanks for possible help.

Edit: Feel like I should specify it. I've googled. Maybe I'm really bad in it, or whatever, but I didn't found how to fix it.

Comment: `memberType.DIRECTORY` should be `memberType::DIRECTORY` or just `DIRECTORY` (since this not an `enum class`, the names are spilled to the enclosing namespace).

Comment: You don't need `struct` in `struct directoryMember tmp;` in C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, the return type of `defineDirectoryMember` is not `void`, so it must return something using `return` statement or abort execution like throwing exceptions.
It seems you wanted to return `tmp`.

Secondly, `memberType` is not a variable name but a type name, so `::` should be used instead of `.` to separate with its member.

```
#include <string>

enum memberType {DIRECTORY, EXECUTABLE, BASIC}; // Types member can be (basic - default file)
struct directoryMember{ // Directory member basic structure
    std::string name;
    std::string ext;
    memberType type;
};
directoryMember defineDirectoryMember(std::string n, std::string e, memberType t){ // Returns structure from raw parameters
    struct directoryMember tmp;
    tmp.name = n;
    tmp.ext = e;
    tmp.type = t;
    return tmp; // add this
}

const directoryMember previousDirectory = defineDirectoryMember("..", "", memberType::DIRECTORY); // use :: instead of .
```

Comment: Thank you kind stranger. It worked. Also looks like I became too interested in debugging that forgot about return. Thanks for reminding too.